# how read specific data from json file without element name in JS

Tags: javascript, json

how i can parse or read specific data from JSON file without element name, for example, i need read in javascript file only row value '$ 16000' and '988980003697VO', how would can to get these value.

I working with JSON file generated for PHP and datatables

This is my JSON file example:

```
{
        "draw": 0,
        "recordsTotal": null,
        "recordsFiltered": null,
        "data": [
            [
                "hola",
                "1",
                "<a href=\"detalles.php?id=MUVzY2FuTW90b3IuY29t \">Thinkcar - Thinkscan MAX</a>",
                "2021-06-21",
                "$ 1.091.000\n",
                "$ 8.000\n",
                "$ 16.000\n",
                "$ 1.115.000\n",
                "$ 1.949.000\n",
                "$ 834.000\n",
                "76%",
                "988980003697VO"
            ],
```

My JS code from datatable

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        var employeeData = $('#escanmotorList').DataTable({
            "lengthChange": true,
            "processing":true,
            "serverSide":true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "order":[],
            "ajax":{
                url:"action.php",
                type:"POST",
                data:{action:'listEscanmotor'},
                dataType:"json"
            },
            "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ productos por página",
                "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
                "info": "Página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                "search": "Buscar",
                "processing":     "Procesando...",
                "paginate": {
                    "first":      "Primero",
                    "last":       "Último",
                    "next":       "Siguiente",
                    "previous":   "Anterior"
                },
                "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
            },
            "columns": [
        { "width": "15px", "targets": 1, "className":      'details-control' },     
        { "width": "15px", "targets": 1 },
        null,
        { "width": "55px", "targets": 1 },
        { "width": "90px", "targets": 1 },
        { "width": "40px", "targets": 1 },
        { "width": "40px", "targets": 1 },
        { "width": "90px", "targets": 1 },
        { "width": "90px", "targets": 1, "orderable": false },
        { "width": "70px", "targets": 1 },
        { "width": "30px", "targets": 1, "orderable": false },
        { "width": "120px", "targets": 1, "orderable": false },
        { "width": "70px", "targets": 1 },  
        { "width": "60px", "targets": 1, "orderable": false },
        { "width": "60px", "orderable": false },
        { "width": "60px", "orderable": false }
      ],
            "pageLength": 10
        });
```

my function where y tray load external JSON data for to show

```
function format ( data ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+data.[6]+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+data.[11]+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first you would use JSON.parse() to convert the JSON into an object.
Then grab the data item, and retrieve the array values by array row number, assuming that's the only thing you know about it.

```js
//EXAMPLE JSON STRING
    let jsonstring = "{\"draw\":0,\"recordsTotal\":null,\"recordsFiltered\":null,\"data\":[[\"hola\",\"1\",\"<ahref=\\\"detalles.php?id=MUVzY2FuTW90b3IuY29t\\\">Thinkcar-ThinkscanMAX<\/a>\",\"2021-06-21\",\"$1.091.000\",\"$8.000\",\"$16.000\",\"$1.115.000\",\"$1.949.000\",\"$834.000\",\"76%\",\"988980003697VO\"]]}"
    
    
    let obj = JSON.parse(jsonstring)
    let data = obj.data
    
    //now data contains the value of the 'data' key in the JSON file.
    //which is a single item parent array
    let data_array = data[0]
    //now data contains array inside of that parent array
    
    //you can retrieve the values of this array the way you want.
    // e.g. looping: 
    data_array.forEach((value, index) => {
        document.write(`index ${index}: ${value}<br>`)
    })
    
    //or accessing directly through their index in the array.
    document.write(`<h4>index 6: ${data_array[6]}</h4>`)
    document.write(`<h4>index 11: ${data_array[11]}</h4>`)
```

Comment: Hi, i upload my complet code, i noob en js im sorry

Comment: @Camilo one thing that may be causing you trouble is that the json snippet you pasted above is missing a ] and a }. also JSON doesn't like it when the last item has a comma. 
so your json data may be corrupt / invalid. 
once you fix that (check output here: https://jsonlint.com/) 
do 
`let jsonstring = **your JSON string**
let obj = JSON.parse(jsonstring)
let obj_data_array = obj.data[0]
let whatever_field_name = obj_data_array[6]`